# Novice/Beginner Javascript Request

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

### HTML code:

```
<td>
<img src="../images/items/333.png"><br>
<b>Product One</b><br>
(2 in stock)<br>
<i>65 USD</i><br>
<form action="shopping.php?shop=1&amp;item=333&amp;price=65&amp;buy=conf&amp;type=" method="post">
<input name="" value="Buy this item" type="submit">
</form></td>

<td>
<img src="../images/items/444.png"><br>
<b>Product Two</b><br>
(4 in stock)<br>
<i>5 USD</i><br>
<form action="shopping.php?shop=1&amp;item=444&amp;price=5&amp;buy=conf&amp;type=" method="post">
<input name="" value="Buy" type="submit">
</form></td>
```

This is the html code on the page I'm working on, the html code cannot be altered.
There are several td tags on the page which contains the following information you see in the code above.

### I would like to write a script that would do something like this:

```
if (document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("Product One") > -1) {
document.location = "shopping.php?shop=1&amp;item="+itemID+"&amp;price="+USD+"&amp;buy=conf&amp;type="
}
```

Search the body/td of the page for the "Product Name" specified in my script, and then if it's found, go to the url that contains variables that need to be extracted, itemID and USD.

***itemID*** is extracted from the src of the image.png by taking the numbers. For example, the itemID of `../images/items/444.png` is 444.

***USD*** is extracted from the price defined between the italics tags. For example the extracted value for USD for`<i>5 USD</i>` would be 5.

### Catch is

I would need **a lot** of `if (document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("Name") > -1) {document.location = "shopping.php?shop=1&amp;item="+itemID+"&amp;price="+USD+"&amp;buy=conf&amp;type="}` to cater to the large number of products I would specify. I might want to specify "Product One to Hundred" and "Sub-product A to Z"

### Solution

Some ways I thought of to handle this (needs to be put into javascript code) is to:

1. Put list of products I will specify into an array (something like) `var list = new Array ("Product One","Product Two","Sub-Product A");` and have a function check the page for the presence of any product from this array that displays on the page.
2. When the product is found, to get the itemID, isolate the numbers before `.png` and after `/items/` from the image src of the product. And to get USD, get the value between the `<i> </i>` tags and only take the numerical values
3. To do this I think `nextSibling` or `previousSibing` can be used, but I'm not too sure about that.
4. Alternatively, to make it easier, there could be a function to immediately locate the form's action value and set the `window.location` since `<form action="shopping.php?shop=1&amp;item=444&amp;price=5&amp;buy=conf&amp;type=" method="post">`
5. I've seen this done before using XPath?

Comment: +1 extaordinary problem description.

Comment: How would your generated URL differ from the URL in the `<form>`? Also, please explain why you are doing all this? Seems like a pointless exercise to me...

Comment: Combination of points 1 and 4 seems to be the simplest approach, as you already have all the data in the form action and just need to traverse the DOM from the _found_ `<b>` to the `<form>` sibling.

Comment: @Tomalak The generated URL wouldn't be different from that of the form's. Using the form's action would reduce the need to define itemID and USD variables.

Comment: @andyb Yes, points 1 and 4 reduces the need to fine other things that point 2 would require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not difficult using jQuery -- especially if we extend it to search for case-insensitive, regular expressions.

The following script should work with the HTML structure from the question, **if it is precisely accurate** and not added by AJAX.   Note the power that regular expressions give when targeting product descriptions.

**You can [see the underlying code at work at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yc5Y/1/).**

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Auto-follow targeted product links.
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var targetList  = [
    "Shoes, pumps",
    "Horse shoes",
    "(?:Red|Pink|Burgundy)\\s+shoes?"
];

/*--- Extend jQuery with a case-insensitive version of contains().
    Also allows regular expressions.
*/
jQuery.extend (
    jQuery.expr[':'].containsCI = function (a, i, m) {
        //--- The next is faster than jQuery(a).text()...
        var sText   = (a.textContent || a.innerText || "");     

        var zRegExp = new RegExp (m[3], 'i');

        return zRegExp.test (sText);
    }
);

$.each (targetList, function (index, value) { 
    var jqSelector          = 'td > b:containsCI("' + value + '")';
    var productFound        = $(jqSelector);
    if (productFound.length) {
        var matchingForm    = productFound.first ().nextAll ("form");
        if (matchingForm.length) {
            alert (productFound.text () );
            document.location   = matchingForm.attr ("action");
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: How would this script handle the event that both "Horse shoes" and "Pink Shoes" are on the page? Which would it buy?
Also, could you explain `"Shoes, pumps",
    "Horse shoes",
    "(?:Red|Pink|Burgundy)\s+shoes?"`

Comment: The script will go to the first item in the list that is found.  In that case, "Horse shoes" because they are first in the list.  Note that this ***is*** the way the question describes the problem.  ... ... `"Shoes, pumps", "Horse shoes", "(?:Red|Pink|Burgundy)\s+shoes?"` is just a sample list of arbitrary product descriptions -- except that `(?:Red|Pink|Burgundy)\s+shoes?` is a regular expression that matches any of those 3 colors followed by any number of spaces (often you THINK it's one space and it's not) and either "shoe" or "shoes".

Comment: According to my testing it will go for the last item in the list that is present on the page. Also, how would you add the function to `alert(Product Name)` while the page is being redirected

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/3Yc5Y/2/.  Notice how it alerts for *Brake shoe* (item 333 on that page) before *Red shoe* (item 444)?  It's because it searches the list from first to last. Anyway, to add that alert, place `alert (productFound.text () );` as shown in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not rely on external libraries like jQuery:

```
function findProducts(referenceList) {  
  var productsOnPage = {}, listMatches = {},
      tds = document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),
      bold, form, i, productName, productUrl;

  // build an index of products on the page (HTML scraping)
  for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    bold = tds[i].getElementsByTagName("B")[0];
    form = tds[i].getElementsByTagName("FORM")[0];

    if (bold && form) {
      productName = bold.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      productUrl  = form.action;

      productsOnPage[productName] = productUrl;
    }
  }

  // match reference list against all available products on the page
  for (i = 0; i < referenceList.length; i++) {
    productName = referenceList[i].toLowerCase();
    productUrl  = productsOnPage[productName];

    listMatches[productName] = productUrl;
  }

  return listMatches;
}
```

Call it:

```
var availableProducts = findProducts(["Product One","Product Two","Sub-Product A"]);
```

After that you'd have an object `availableProducts` that's looking like this:

```
{
  "product one": "shopping.php?shop=1&item=333&price=65&buy=conf&type=",
  "product two": "shopping.php?shop=1&item=444&price=5&buy=conf&type=",
  "sub-product a": undefined
}
```

Note that all keys are lower case to make string comparisons consistent. To look up a product you would use

```
function navigateIfAvailable(productName) {
  var url = availableProducts[productName.toLowerCase()];

  if (url) document.location = url;
}
```

Now

```
navigateIfAvailable("Product Two");
```

would go somewhere. Or not.